# mPDF with Laravel displaying symbols

Tags: laravel, mpdf

I'm using mPDF with Laravel and ReactJS.

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['format' => 'Legal']);
$mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($page1);
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($page2);
$mpdf->Output("AlMokhtabar.pdf", "I");
```

But the problem with the output is its shows symbols like the following.

> %PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <> /Contents 4 0 R>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream
> x�ݖMO�0�sί�

I've used the header to change to "Content-Type: application/pdf" and using "D" to download the file, but if I use "F" and "S," it shows nothing.

Comment: if I used **"F"** or **"S"** it will return Blank-White Page and if used **"D"** or **"I"** it will shown Symbols

Comment: It is literally a page of the manual https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/strange-character-output-in-browser.html